# How does one use C# in SCSS Conditionals?

Tags: c#, sass, asp.net-core-mvc

I am currently trying to achieve something I think is quite simple:
Changing a background colour based on the role of the logged-in user.

I've got an if/if else setup in the SCSS already, but currently it's just using a hardcoded string.
I also know how to get the string value of the current user's role...

I do not know how to use C# things in SCSS though. When I discovered that '@{}' is used for implementing if/else etc, I naturally tried "@inject" and "@using"... but that didn't work, sadly.

How do I use C# code in SASS?

Comment: You don't. SCSS is converted to CSS at compiletime, no SCSS code is run at runtime. Just add a class ("user", "admin", "somerole") to the html or body at runtime and style that.

Comment: hint - consider using a separate `body` class

Comment: @DanielA.White I should clarify: I'm only trying to change the bg colour of a div, not the entire body. I assume that you mentioned using a separate `body` class based on the idea of me trying to set the background of the entire body?

Comment: no, you just get a more specific selector - its a common place to put it on the body/html since its a nice root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this is done with a separate class on either the `html` or `body` elements. You can do this easily with Razor.

```
<html class="loggedin">
```

Then you just define custom overrides based on the selector.

```
html.loggedin
{
   // do your custom stuff in this block.
}
```

Comment: I see... you mention "based on the selector", but I must be missing something very basic... To me, 'Selectors' is simply referring to things like:

'#id{}'
'.class{}'
'element{}'

I don't understand how to access the role of the logged in user from CSS or SCSS... 
Via C# I'd do `_userManager.GetRolesAsync(User)'

Comment: @MJDeveloping you set it in your html via a razor code. don't do it in the css.

Comment: DanielA.White You probably should edit the question... it is very unclear how your answer relates to the question as asked.

Comment: @DanielA.White Oh. I see, I was making things harder than they needed to be... Thanks!